# I lost my files in the repository of GitHub after doing push --mirror

Tags: git, github

I just wanted to move my codes in the repository to other my repository and did this.

```
git clone --mirror [repository1 which has codes i wanted to move]
git remote set-url --push origin [repository2 which has other codes]
$ git push --mirror
```

and i lost my all codes of repository2 and repository1 was pasted to repository2.

can i just restore every codes of the repository2? or is there any way to undo what i did?

I googled a lot but it seems to be that no one had similar problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked out the Git reflog?

Comment: Your tags mention GitHub. GitHub never drop any commits from a repository, so you can ask GitHub Support to restore access to lost commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How different was repository2 from repository1? If repository1 was just ahead of repository2 in the historical timeline, then git will allow you to revert back to the specific commits that you are hoping to find. However if they were divergent, I would be surprised if your commands even worked if you did not include a `--force` flag with your `git push --mirror` command. Git has checks in place to prevent this very scenario, but I'm not certain if the `--mirror` flag overrides that protection or not as that is the job of the `--force` flag. If not `--force` flag was issued with your `git push` then I am certain that somewhere in your git history are the files you are looking for. Perhaps they are in a different branch or maybe detached. Without knowing the specifics around the changes to code being made, your branching strategy, and what you have done, nobody here is going to be able to help you beyond the points I've already made.

However if you did issue a `git push --mirror --force` then all bets are off and you very well may have destroyed data.

Comment: Thank you for answer. all i did is that 1. git clone --mirror [repository 1]    2. cd [repository 1].git    3. git remote set-url --push origin [repository 2]    4. git push --mirror                          and how can i check my historical timline??

Comment: use the command `gitk` for a gui. you can also use any other 3rd party gui tools to inspect git timeline. Note that unlike other git commands `gitk` has no space after `git`. If you want to inspect history using the cli, I believe `git show` is the right command.

Comment: Thank you so much. by the way, do u have any more ideas for restoring my files? i'm just new to git and github. So I feel like I'm lost somewhere... i really appreciate it. Thank you again.

Comment: Loosing files while using git is very difficult, but not impossible. When it happens, it demonstrates reckless use of or a misunderstanding of what git is. Please be careful to learn the very few commands which "rewrite history" as these are the distructive ones and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Unless you have a clone of repository2 that was taken before you pushed the damages changes to it, that data is lost.